# Pegar o próximo input depois de um input (object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Quero pegar o objecto do 2º input.
Como tenho mais inputs com a class 'check-date2', quero pegar o elemento imediatamente a seguir ao primeiro.

HTML

```
<div class="form_line">
                <div class="column-50">
                    <div class="line_desc">
                        Data Início<font>*</font>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line_field">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="datepicker1"
                                class="form-control  input date-check check-date"
                                placeholder="Data Início - DD-MM-YYYY" type="text"
                                name="event_date_start">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column-50">
                    <div class="line_desc">
                        Data Fim<font>*</font>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line_field">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="datepicker2"
                                class="form-control input date-check check-date2"
                                placeholder="Data Fim - DD-MM-YYYY" type="text"
                                name="event_date_end">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

No .js tenho isto:

```
$(".check-date").on("change", function() {
    checkIfSecondDateIsGreaterThanFirst(this);
});
```

E a função que deve pegar o objecto do input:

```
function checkIfSecondDateIsGreaterThanFirst(date) {
/**
 * to verify that the second data is greater than the first
 */
var next_date = $(date).next('.check-date2');
alert($(next_date).attr('class'));
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o input está dentro da div com classe `.column-50` e ambas as divs `.column-50` são seguidas podes fazer assim:

```
function checkIfSecondDateIsGreaterThanFirst(date) {
    var next_date = $(date).closest('.column-50').next().find('.check-date2');
    alert($(next_date).val('class'));
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rok7cd8z/

- `.closest()` sobe no DOM até a `div.column-50`
- `.next()` seleciona a `div.column-50` seguinte
- `.find('.check-date2')` escolhe o input dentro dessa `div.column-50`

Comment: Era isso mesmo o que queria, está a funcionar

Como faço o contrário, estando no 2º input e pegar o valor do primeiro input?

Comment: @M_b_85 em vêz de `.next()` usa `.prev()`.